# Recursive Ajax call used for progress indicator. Works in IE/Chrome but not in FireFox/Safari

Tags: javascript, ajax, sockets

I've got an ASP-NET/MVC/Bootstrap app in which I've implemented a progress bar that displays in a modal window during a long running search process.

The sequence of events is this:

User clicks button to initiate process.  This button submits the form.  There is an on-click event on the button that calls a javascript function (showProcessingModal()) to show the modal window and then initiate the recursive ajax callback that gets the status of the process and displays it in the modal:

```
    var searchCancel;

    function showProcessingModal() {
        var sid = performance.now();
        $("#SearchId").val(sid);
        $("#PleaseWaitModal").modal("show");
        getSearchProgress(sid);
    }

    function getSearchProgress(sid) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SearchProgress")',
            method: "POST",
            data: { SearchId: sid },
            success: function (result) {
                $('.progress-bar').css('width', result.pct + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', result.pct);
                if (result.msg != "") {
                    $('#ProgressMessage').html(result.msg);
                }
                if (result.pct == 100) {
                    $('.progress-bar').removeClass('active')
                }
                if (result.pct <= 100) {
                    searchCancel = setTimeout(function () {
                        getSearchProgress(sid);
                    }, 500);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

This works beautifully in IE and Chrome.  In FireFox, the modal shows but the ajax call fails because it seems FireFox has closed the socket on account of the page being submitted.  I'm assuming Safari is doing the same although with Safari, the modal doesn't even show.  I have yet debugged why.

I'm suspecting that I'm going to have to go a different route to make this work for all browsers.  I'm thinking that the form post is what's messing things up.

Thoughts anyone?

Comment: Prevent the form from submitting, then in the complete callback of the ajax call resubmit the form. It's not really clear where the event handler for the form is ?

Comment: I agree that (submit form via standard form submit) + (ajax piece to display form progress) probably won't  work in all browsers. Can you do (submit form via ajax + ajax piece to display form progress) + (location.href to next page when complete) ?

Comment: As it stands now, I can't really prevent the form from submitting because the form post is what initiates the search.  When the search is complete, the user is redirected to a different page.

Comment: Can you not change form onsubmit handler to send form by ajax instead?

Comment: @James, I'm not sure how I would accomplish that.  If the ajax does the form submit, how do I redirect to the results page and preserve the view that was returned by the MVC Post?